# cor.test ,"not enough finite observations"

Tags: r

I use two different ways to use `cor.test`, one in my own function, the other uses `cor.test` directly. When I use `cor.test` in my own function, it appeared an error, how could it happen?

This was **OK**

```
cor.test(x=cust_new$maintain_cust/cust_new$ttl_cust,
         y=cust_new$ttl_cust,alternative="two.sided",
         method="pearson",conf.level=0.95)
```

The following would give the error :

> "not enough finite observations"

```
cor_result<-function(x,y,data){
  a<-cor.test(x=as.numeric(data$x)/as.numeric(data$y),
              y=as.numeric(data$y),
              alternative="two.sided",method="spearman",
              conf.level=0.95)
  r<-a$estimate
  p<-a$p.value
  c<-data.frame(r=r,p=p)
  return(c)
}

d<-cor_result(x=maintain_cust,y=ttl_cust,data=cust_new)
```

The following would give the error :

> 'y' must be a numeric vector"

```
cor_result<-function(x,y,data){
  a<-cor.test(x=data$x/data$y,y=data$y,
            alternative="two.sided",method="spearman",conf.level=0.95)
  r<-a$estimate
  p<-a$p.value
  c<-data.frame(r=r,p=p)
  return(c)
}

d<-cor_result(x=maintain_cust,y=ttl_cust,data=cust_new)
```

**dput(cust_new),a few sample**:

```
structure(list(data_month = structure(c(16953, 16983, 17014, 
17045, 17075, 17106, 16953, 16983, 17014, 17045), class = "Date"), 
    ttl_cust = c(383L, 580L, 735L, 850L, 952L, 1062L, 2418L, 
    2492L, 2515L, 2550L), maintain_cust = c(179L, 266L, 355L, 
    413L, 448L, 508L, 935L, 1026L, 1091L, 1143L)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("data_month", "ttl_cust", 
"maintain_cust"))
```

Comment: Could you please use `dput(cust_new)`  and paste the results into your question so that we could reproduce your results?

Comment: You are not using `x` and `y` inside your `cor_result` function at all.

Comment: I use x and y.x=as.numeric(data$x)/as.numeric(data$y),
              y=as.numeric(data$y),

Answer (score 2):

You are not properly passing vector (i.e., dataframe column) into function. Consider passing string literals of data frame columns to be referenced with double brackets (and `as.numeric()` may not be necessary if columns are numeric types):

```
cor_result<-function(x, y, data){ 
   a<-cor.test(x=as.numeric(data[[x]])/as.numeric(data[[y]]),y=as.numeric(data[[y]]),
               alternative="two.sided", method="spearman", conf.level=0.95) 
   r<-a$estimate 
   p<-a$p.value 
   c<-data.frame(r=r,p=p) 
   return(c) 
}

d<-cor_result(x="maintain_cust", y="ttl_cust", data=cust_new)
```

Alternatively without *data* argument:

```
cor_result<-function(x, y){ 
   a<-cor.test(x=(x/y),y=y,
               alternative="two.sided", method="spearman", conf.level=0.95) 
   r<-a$estimate 
   p<-a$p.value 
   c<-data.frame(r=r,p=p) 
   return(c) 
}

d<-cor_result(x=cust_new$maintain_cust, y=cust_new$ttl_cust)
```

Answer (score 1):

At root I think this is a confusion about the way to refer to columns within a data set.  In particular, when using `$`-indexing the symbols after the `$` interpreted *literally*. When you refer to `data$x` and `data$y` in your first function, R is looking for columns named "x" and "y" in your `data` object. These don't exist in your data frame, so `NULL` is returned (it would arguably be better if R threw an error in this case, but oh well ...)

- In your first function you use `as.numeric()`.  `as.numeric(NULL)` returns `numeric(0)` (a zero-length numeric vector). Therefore, `cor.test` is trying to compute the correlation between two zero-length objects, and understandably throws the "not enough finite observations" error. (Try `cor.test(numeric(0),numeric(0))` to replicate.)
- In your second function you don't translate to numeric so you are instead executing `cor.test(NULL,NULL)`, which gives the "must be a numeric vector" error.

So what can you do?

- @Parfait's suggestion #1: pass `x` and `y` as strings and use `[[`-indexing rather than `$`-indexing
- @Parfait's suggestion #2: pass `x` and `y` as objects (i.e., don't look for them in `data`)

If you really want to (1) use a `data` argument and (2) pass the values as symbols it gets tricker to do things properly.

- The easiest way would be to call `deparse(substitute(x))` to retrieve the *name* of the symbol used as a string, then use `[[`-indexing
- Otherwise you can use `eval`, if you use it carefully.  For example:

```
f <- function(a,b,data=dd) {
   eval(substitute(a/b,list(a=quote(x),b=quote(y))),envir=dd)
}
dd <- data.frame(x=1,y=2)
## set x and y to other values in the global env 
##   so we can see that we got the right ones ...  
x <- 3
y <- 4
f(x,y)
## 0.5
```